# Nothing show in Adapter when I use AsyncListDiffer and view binding

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

**I try to show data form api in Custom recycler view by using view binding and diffUtil**

**I try to use DiffUtil with Binding view in RecyclerView Adapter
but when I send the data from fragment differ.submitList(the DATA)
nothing the show in the list**

**when I debugging I found the data come from API and go to differ**

```
class NewsAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<NewsAdapter.ItemViewHolder>() {

private val differCallBack = object : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Article>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem.url == newItem.url
    }

    override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem: Article, newItem: Article): Boolean {
        return oldItem == newItem
    }
}

val differ = AsyncListDiffer(this, differCallBack)


override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    return ItemViewHolder(
        LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.item_article_preview, parent, false)
    )
}

inner class ItemViewHolder(private val view: View) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view) {
    var binding =
        ItemArticlePreviewBinding.bind(view)

    fun bind(article: Article) {
        Glide.with(view).load(article.urlToImage).into(binding.ivArticleImage)
        binding.tvTitle.text = article.title
        binding.tvSource.text = article.source.name
        binding.tvDescription.text = article.description
        binding.tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
    }
}


override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ItemViewHolder, position: Int) {
    val article = differ.currentList[position]
    holder.itemView.apply {
        holder.bind(article)
        setOnClickListener {
            onItemClickListener?.let {
                it(article)
            }
        }
    }
}

private var onItemClickListener: ((Article) -> Unit)? = null

fun setOnClickListener(listener: (Article) -> Unit) {
    onItemClickListener = listener
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return differ.currentList.size
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `ItemViewHolder`, the `itemView` you are binding data to, and the `itemView` you are passing to the `recyclerView` are two different views.

The `view` which you have passed to `ItemViewHolder` after creating from `onCreateViewHolder` is being passed to the `RecyclerView`, but you are binding data to a different `view` that you are inflating using the `viewBinding` of the `ItemArticlePreviewBinding`.

You can change `ViewHolder`'s constructor to accept a `binding` instance instead of a `view` and then bind data to that `binding` object.

```
inner class ItemViewHolder(private val binding: ItemArticlePreviewBinding) :
    RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

    fun bind(article: Article) {
        Glide.with(view).load(article.urlToImage).into(binding.ivArticleImage)
        binding.tvTitle.text = article.title
        binding.tvSource.text = article.source.name
        binding.tvDescription.text = article.description
        binding.tvPublishedAt.text = article.publishedAt
    }
}
```

Inside `onCreateViewHolder` inflate a `ViewBinding` object and pass that to the `ItemViewHolder`'s constructor

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ItemViewHolder {
    return ItemViewHolder(
        ItemArticlePreviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, I tried it but the problem persists

Comment: How are you getting instance of `differ` in the fragment?

Comment: newsAdapter.differ.submitList(newsResponse.articles)

Comment: This should work, you should try debugging if the flow is going inside the adapter or not.

Comment: Hello I found the bug 
I send to fragment a view in Fragment(R.layout.fragmentnew) and put the binging in onViewCreated but I should put it in onCreateView